# Differentiation of Parabolic Cylinder Functions and Hermite Polynomials w.r.t to Order

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, functions, special-functions

When I evaluated (ver. 12.3) parabolic functions below in the vanishing order limit:  $u \rightarrow 0$, I got the following:

```
In[347]:= FullSimplify[
 Limit[-I 2^(-1 - u/2) b^(-u/2)
    Gamma[u] (E^((I a c)/(4 b))
       ParabolicCylinderD[-u, (-I a - c)/(Sqrt[2] Sqrt[b])] - 
     E^(-((I a c)/(4 b)))
       ParabolicCylinderD[-u, (I a - c)/(Sqrt[2] Sqrt[b])] + 
     E^(-((I a c)/(4 b)))
       ParabolicCylinderD[-u, (-I a + c)/(Sqrt[2] Sqrt[b])] - 
     E^((I a c)/(4 b))
       ParabolicCylinderD[-u, (I a + c)/(Sqrt[2] Sqrt[b])]), u -> 0]]

Out[347]= 1/2 I E^(((a - c) (a + c))/(8 b)) (-
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(HermiteH\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"1", ",", "0"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[0, (I (a + I c))/(2 Sqrt[b])] + 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(HermiteH\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"1", ",", "0"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[0, (-I a + c)/(2 Sqrt[b])] + 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(HermiteH\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"1", ",", "0"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[0, -((I a + c)/(2 Sqrt[b]))] - 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(HermiteH\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"1", ",", "0"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[0, (I a + c)/(2 Sqrt[b])])
```

which in the TexForm reads

$$
\frac{1}{2} i e^{\frac{(a-c) (a+c)}{8 b}} \left(-\text{HermiteH}^{(1,0)}\left(0,\frac{i (a+i c)}{2
   \sqrt{b}}\right)+\text{HermiteH}^{(1,0)}\left(0,\frac{c-i a}{2 \sqrt{b}}\right)+\text{HermiteH}^{(1,0)}\left(0,-\frac{c+i a}{2
   \sqrt{b}}\right)-\text{HermiteH}^{(1,0)}\left(0,\frac{c+i a}{2 \sqrt{b}}\right)\right)
$$

Above functions evaluate to very specific values but they remain somewhat elusive. I looked through documentation of Hermite polynomials but I could not find much information about special limiting cases of special functions like the ones above. **Edit:** I have realized reading a comment down below that these functions represent derivative with respect to order:

```
In[10]:= N[-D[HermiteH[-n, x], n] /. n -> 0]

Out[10]= 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(HermiteH\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"1", ",", "0"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[0., x]
```

But I could not find Mathematica documentation and definition on how such derivative is implemented.

Comment: Look at the InputForm or FullForm of the output and you will see that the superscripts denote derivatives. See [`Derivative`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Derivative.html)

Comment: You could use `//TeXForm` at the end of your output in Mathematica then put output in-between dollar-signs. I think it would draw more attention to show: $\frac{1}{2} i e^{\frac{(a-c) (a+c)}{8 b}}
   \left(-\text{HermiteH}^{(1,0)}\left(0,\frac{i (a+i c)}{2
   \sqrt{b}}\right)+\text{HermiteH}^{(1,0)}\left(0,\frac{c-i a}{2
   \sqrt{b}}\right)+\text{HermiteH}^{(1,0)}\left(0,-\frac{c+i a}{2
   \sqrt{b}}\right)-\text{HermiteH}^{(1,0)}\left(0,\frac{c+i a}{2
   \sqrt{b}}\right)\right)$

Comment: Derivatives of eigenfunctions of operators wrt to eigenvalues don't make sense, generally, because the spectrum is the exceptional set where the operators are not invertible. Conpare$$ \lim_{\pi\to 0}\ d/d\pi\ sin( n \  \pi \  x)$$